# video playing from application background to foreground takes 2 seconds lagging from pause to play in iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have `VideoController` which plays video. Now VideoController is pushed in `navigationController`.

```
 VideoController *ObjVideoController = [[VideoController alloc] init];
 ObjVideoController.strVideoURL = [AnimationArr objectAtIndex:SequenceCount];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:ObjVideoController animated:NO];
 [ObjVideoController play:[AnimationArr objectAtIndex:SequenceCount]];
```

`Play method` in VideoController is like this:

```
 - (void)play:(NSString*)videoFile {
    playbaktime = 0.0;

    NSBundle *main = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[main resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoFile]];

    if (!self.ctl)
    {
        self.ctl = nil;
        self.ctl = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]init];
        [self.view addSubview:self.ctl.view];
    }
    [self.ctl prepareToPlay];
    self.ctl.contentURL = url;
    self.ctl.controlStyle = 0;
    //self.ctl.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
    [self.ctl.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        [self.ctl.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,480,320)];
    else
        [self.ctl.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];

    self.ctl.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.ctl play];
}
```

Now `observer` has been add for `UIApplicationWillResignActive`, `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`. Its selector are given below:

```
 -(void)Pause_Video:(NSNotification*)notification {
   Pausevideo = 1;
   playbaktime = self.ctl.currentPlaybackTime;
   [self.ctl pause];
 }

-(void)Play_Video:(NSNotification*)notification {

  if(self.ctl.loadState == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
  {
    [self play:self.strVideoURL];
    Pausevideo = 0;
  }
  else{
    if (self.ctl.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
        [self.ctl play];
        Pausevideo = 0;
    } 
    else
    {
        [self.ctl setInitialPlaybackTime:playbaktime];
        [self.ctl play];
        Pausevideo = 0;
    }
   }  
  }
```

Hope u understood question and help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could improve the format of the code, or at least comment it if you expect to receive more replies.

Comment: Just nitpicking - don't use `Pausevideo`, but `pauseVideo`. Don't use `Play_Video`, but `playVideo`. Read something about ObjC conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be calling `prepareToPlay` every time before playing, this is not necessary, just call it once when you load the file. There is no need to call it after you pause.

Additionally, you are incurring a lag because notifications do not fire instantly. Specifically, `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` only fires well after the app has entered the foreground. What you want instead is to observe the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`, which will fire as the app is entering the foreground, and allow you to decrease the lag significantly.

Comment: it doesnot have any issue in iOS 5.1 or less verson